# partial functions basics

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> $f: \mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{N}$ is defined as
>   $$
> f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 2x-1, & \text{$x \gt 0$} \\
> -2x,  & \text{$x \le 0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> - one to one proof
> - f is onto proof
> - determine $f^{-1}$

Confused on how to begin. I'm not very strong at proofs.

Comment: Do you know what "one-to-one" means? Do you know what "onto" means? Do you know what $f^{-1}$ means? Those are good places to start...

Comment: yes! f^-1 is the inverse of the function. one to one means that only one function of Z can be mapped to one function of N.. a bit rusty on onto though..

Comment: One to one is also called injective, onto surjective...not quite sure what you mean by"function of Z"

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of the terms however just a bit unsure on how to proceed considering this has two intervals.

Comment: You mean >0 and <=0?

Comment: yes, sadly there are no examples like this in the textbook either

Comment: If you really find it hard to digest all these definitions you may start by just "experimenting" with the function, instead of looking at Z you could start with N, what properties has the function (image is odd,even...)

Comment: It seems matthew needs to discuss this with a live instructor.  For someone with his confusions, that method will work much better for him than either (a) back-and-forth discussions on-line or (b) someone simply writing down the solution for him.

Comment: I definitely would! thanks for the advice!!

Answer (score 0):

To show $f$ is one-to-one: Assume $f(b)=f(a)$ and show that this implies $b=a$. You will need to be careful applying the definition of $f$ separately on different intervals.

To show $f$ is onto: Show that for all $c$ in $\mathbb{N}$ there is some element $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x)=c$

To find $f^{-1}(x)$: Assume $f(y)=x$ and solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. Again, you will need to careful with using $f$ because it means different things on different intervals.

Comment: in our case, what is a and b? that's the problem im having that I'm not sure how to use to the definition on different intervals. if it was just one interval, then it would be different. The same goes for other questions..

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary points. You will have four different cases based on where $a$ and $b$ belong on the real line.

Answer (score 0):

$a)$ Start with $f(x) = f(y)$. If $x,y $ have the same sign, say both positive, then $2x-1=2y-1 \Rightarrow x = y$. If they have opposite signs, say $x < 0, y \geq 0$, then $-2x = 2y-1$. This can't happen since the left side is even while the right side is odd. Thus $f$ is one-to-one.

$b)$ Let $y \in \mathbb{N}$, if $y$ is odd, then set $x = \dfrac{1+y}{2}$, then $f(x) = y$, and if $y$ is even, then set $x = -\dfrac{y}{2}$, then again $f(x) = y$, and $f$ is onto.

$c)$ from part $b)$, $f^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1+x}{2} , x \text{ is odd } \\ \dfrac{-x}{2} , x \text{ is even } \end{cases}$